# Wordpress Featured Image only on overview

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a template called 'expression' for Wordpress which works fine.
I'd just like to tweak it a little.
I have a page that shows all my blog posts, and ofcourse each blog post has an own overview if you click on it.

on each blog post you make, you can set a featured image. This image is shown on the overview page, and on each individual detailed view of 1 blog post.
I'm trying to find a way to only show this featured image on the overview page of all blogs, and not on the detailed view of a blog post.

Is there a way to do this?

I tried to edit the code in post-template.php by adding:

```
ispage('blog')
```

full code:

```
if(has_post_thumbnail() && !$hide_thumbnail && !is_page('blog')){ ?>
    <div class="blog-post-img">
        <?php if(!is_single()){?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> 
    <?php }
    $img_id=$pex_page->layout=='full'?'post_box_img_full':'post_box_img';
    the_post_thumbnail($img_id);

     if(!is_single()){
     ?>
    </a>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php 
}
```

this works, but both featured images will be gone. which is not what I wanted.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: please accept your answer, there should be a hollow checkmark next to the answer. This tells us it solves the issue without having to guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it eventually,

you have to use:

```
is_single();
```

instead of :

```
is_page();
```

Thanks anyway.